# socket.io with redis store

Tags: redis, socket.io

I am using socket.io with redis store. I have the following code taken as it is from socket.io website.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({host: '128.199.122.183', port: 6379}));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Code runs as expected but I expected to see some entries (key value pairs) made in redis but didn't find any. Could anyone tell me how I can check if redis is being used by socket.io?

Comment: thanks for this question! It's interesting for me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current `socket.io-redis` package doesn't store anything in the database (though this might change in the future). It uses the redis pub/sub mechanism to distribute messages across different nodes.

To check if its working you need to start more than one instance of your app and then emit messages on one of them and check if all the others are receiving it.

You can also use redis-cli to see if its working.

```
redis-cli
>MONITOR
```

And then emit some messages.

Comment: Thanks for the nice tip. It didn't strike me to start multiple instances and emit messages to see if they are being delivered. If you think about thats the whole point of using redis in the first place. Perhaps I was too deeply thinking about it and missed the actual point why one would use redis for.