# Socket.io with Redis adapter not storing anything on Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io, adapter

I'm using the latest package of Socket.io and need it to be working with the Redis adapter in order to work properly on several Pods/Servers.
The Socket.io is working fine, messages are emitted properly, rooms are created and deleted etc, but I got unexpected behavior when deploing it to the server, for example, not all users get the message all the time.

I figured out that the problem is, that the problem related to the fact that it doesn't actualy use Redis as adapter.
For example, if I look for the RoomName in the redis-cli `SCAN 0 MATCH *RoomName*` i get an empty array.

Here is the code i'm using currently:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import redisAdapter from 'socket.io-redis';
import redis from 'redis';

const pubClient = redis.createClient({ host: REDIS_HOST, port: REDIS_PORT });
const subClient = pubClient.duplicate();
const adapter = redisAdapter(pubClient, subClient);

let io = null;

const WebSocketsManager = {
  init: (server) => {
    io = new Server(server, {
      origins: '*:*',
      path: '/public/socket.io',
    });
    io.adapter(adapter);

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      //   Just logging it 
      });

      socket.on('enteredRoomName', async (data) => {
        const roomName = WebSocketsManager.getRoomName(data, 'RoomName');

        socket.join(roomName);
        const room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName);
        console.log(`User ${socket.id} has joined the room '${roomName}' (total users in this room: ${room.size})`)
      });

      socket.on('exitedRoomName', async (data) => {
        const roomName = WebSocketsManager.getRoomName(data, 'RoomName');
        WebSocketsManager.exitRoom(roomName, socket);
      });
    });
  },
  getRoomName: (data, actionType) => {
  // Some logic to create room name
  },
  exitRoom: (roomName, socket) => {
    socket.leave(roomName);
    const room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName);
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} has left the room '${roomName}' (total users in this room: ${room.size})`)
  },
};
```

Another thing i've tried, is make sure that i have connection and can write to Redis.

I've tried to add this code inside the 'enteredRoomName' callback function:

```
await pubClient.set('mykey2', 'myvalue', (err, reply) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log('Key saved successfully in Redis!');
          }
        });
```

And actually saw that nothing happens, i've got error of "The client is closed".

But if i use the **ioredis** package, to connect (`pubClient = new Redis();`), i get the new key in redis.

But still nothing in redis, if i use it as parameters in `redisAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured that out, thank to this thread:
[socket.io with redis store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544614/socket-io-with-redis-store)

I should have start two instances of my app on localhost, to test it properly.
After i did that, I was able to see the SETs and Gets in Redis by using the command `MONITOR` in redis-cli.

Hope it helps someone.

P.S. Also, i had to add `pubClient.connect();` and `subClient.connect();` as it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120056/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-socket-io-with-redis-adapter-on-nest-js). Although it's mentioned in the documentation that it's not needed anymore.